# Where is the air inlet on a Mac mini (2018) for the cooling fan?

Tags: mac, mac-mini, cooling

On the [Mac mini (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini#4th_generation_(USB-C,_2018)), where is the air inlet for cooling the innards of this computer?

I have looked at the [iFixit teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac+mini+Late+2018+Teardown/115210). It shows the fan blowing out the broad outlet across the back of the Mac mini, below the USB-C ports. I certainly can feel the warm air exiting this outlet.

➥ Where does the air *enter* the Mac mini?

The bottom is either solid metal or covered by the non-slip rubber. I see no other inlets on the backside. So I am left puzzled.

I am concerned about not blocking the air inlet, to maximize cooling efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The air inlet on the Mac Mini (2018) is located on the bottom. If you look closely at the circular plastic disc, you'll see that there's a gap between that and the metal part of the computer. This is the air inlet!

The [electromagnetic shielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding) beneath the plastic disc is perforated, allowing air to move. As [shown on iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac+mini+Late+2018+Teardown/115210):

[image]

[image]